# Insert into table and Inner Joining 2 tables in C# Form

Tags: c#, mysql, forms, visual-studio

So I have 4 tables in MySql database, we are going to focus on 2 tables for now.
I have materijal(Material) table and Skart(Scrap) table:

materijal Table (original) witch has :

idmaterijal(INT),
naziv_materijala(VARCHAR),
kolicina_materiala(FLOAT),
mjerna_jedinica(VARCHAR),
sifra_materijala(INT)

material Table(eng) :

idmaterial(INT) ,
name_material(VARCHAR) ,
quantity_material(FLOAT) ,
measuring_unit(VARCHAR) ,
code_material(INT)

skart Table (original) which has:

idskart(INT),
materijal_idmaterijal(INT),
kolicina_skarta(FLOAT)

scrap Table (eng):

idscrap(INT),
material_idmaterial(INT),
quantity_scrap(FLOAT)

They are connected with Non-Identifying Relation 1:1, as you can see in this picture  https://prnt.sc/hdvGuXJWNI0Q  .
I want to Insert materijal_idmaterijal into skart table by choosing the name via comboBox, and kolicina_skarta via textBox, as shown in these pictures :

https://prnt.sc/kbXdQTSJ-wwt - Choosing data on comboBox witch is connected to materijal table and list all naziv_materijal
https://prnt.sc/BMvlle9M9OPI  - Input data in myForm
https://prnt.sc/4rF1Ht30PDNL  - What happens when I click "Snimi" button (INSERT)

This is my code for "Snimi" button :

```
private void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Snimanje Skarta I Update materijal tabele
        {
            konekcija.Open();
            //OleDbCommand komanda = new OleDbCommand();
            MySqlCommand komanda = new MySqlCommand();
            komanda.Connection = konekcija;
            komanda.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            komanda.CommandText = "INSERT INTO skart(materijal_idmaterijal, value) value(select materijal_idmaterijal from materijal WHERE naziv_materijala = '" + comboBox1.Text + "') AND (kolicina_skarta, value) value('" + textBox7.Text + "') "; 
            komanda.CommandText = "UPDATE materijal SET kolicina_materijala = kolicina_materijala - '" + textBox7.Text + "' WHERE naziv_materijala = '" + comboBox1.Text + "' AND kolicina_materijala >= '" + textBox7.Text + "'";
            komanda.ExecuteNonQuery();
            konekcija.Close();
            comboBox1.Text = "";
            textBox7.Text = "";
            MessageBox.Show("Uspjesno ste unijeli izabrani Škart");
        }
```

And this is my "Osvježi" or on Eng "Refresh" button witch refreshes the dataGridView in my Skart panel :

```
private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Osvježi Skart
        {
            konekcija.Open();
            // OleDbCommand komanda = new OleDbCommand();
            MySqlCommand komanda = new MySqlCommand();
            komanda.Connection = konekcija;
            komanda.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            komanda.CommandText = " SELECT naziv_materijala, s.kolicina_skarta, mjerna_jedinica, sifra_materijala FROM skart AS s INNER JOIN materijal AS m ON s.materijal_idmaterijal = m.idmaterijal; ";
            komanda.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            //OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(komanda);
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(komanda);
            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView3.DataSource = dt;
            konekcija.Close(); 
        }
```

It uses Inner Join to merge naziv_materijala, s.kolicina_skarta, mjerna_jedinica, sifra_materijala from materijal table into skart table via idmaterijala.
I want to Insert materijal_idmaterijal into skart table by choosing the name of the naziv_materijal via comboBox, and kolicina_skarta by inserting number in textBox .
The codes up there are my own and it updates kolicina_materijala (eng . quantity_material) in materijal table but it doesn't insert data in skart table. Please Help.
PS: Do keep in mind this is my school project and I am only starting to code in C# and crating Forms, I know my code is not clean and It could look better but I am only concerned on learning how to solve this problem.

Comment: please use ***parameterised queries*** - building SQL queries by concatenation etc. is a recipe for disaster. not only is it a source for many hard to debug syntax errors, it's also a wide, open gate for ***[SQL Injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/)***.

Comment: I will try to learn that for the future but right now I am trying to solve my problem. I cant Insert materijal_idmaterijal into my skart table if you can help I would appreciate it a lot <3

Comment: trust me: learn to do it the right way _now_; the sooner the better. if you "try to learn it in the future" - you won't. and there simply is **no reason** to not use parameterised queries - period. by the way: your error is trivial: when you assign your `UPDATE`-statement to `komanda.CommandText`, you're _overwriting_ the `INSERT`-statement. it never gets executed because you remove it before you execute it... (simplest way: just use a new `MySqlCommand`)

Comment: and by the way: welcome to stackoverflow. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I added a new MySqlCommand and it still doesn't work ...

Comment: could you please _show_ what you've tried?

Comment: var idmaterijal = "SELECT idmaterijal FROM materijal WHERE naziv_materijal = '" + comboBox1 + "'";
            komanda.CommandText = "INSERT INTO skart (materijal_idmaterijal, kolicina_skarta) values( '" + idmaterijal +"' ,'" + textBox7.Text + "')";                         Now I need to store idmaterijal from naziv_materijala witch is shown in comboBox1 to my var idmaterijal

Comment: When I hard Code     :     komanda.CommandText = "INSERT INTO skart (materijal_idmaterijal, kolicina_skarta) values( '" + 2 +"' ,'" + textBox7.Text + "')" it ads the material witch has idmaterijal = 2 . So I just need to extract my idmaterijal from comboBox witch shows naziv_materijala ....

Comment: seems you're just storing the query in a separate _string_... you need to instantiate a `new MySqlCommand()`. also: please ***edit*** your question to add further clarification; multiline-code in comments is basically unreadable.